# vue props passing from parent component to child

Tags: vue.js

I have a container component with a navbar component inside of it. I call an api in beforeCreate, then set variables here, and set them in vue 'state' (data), then pass those as props down to the navbar component. However, these do not appear. What am i doing wrong here?

```
<template>
<Navbar :title='title' />
<template>

<script>
export default{
name:'example',
data(){
    return{
        title:''
    };
},
beforeCreate: function(){
    axios.post('')
    .then(response => {
        this.title = response.title
   })
}
}
</script>
```

I have console logged the response data from the api, so i know it is producing data properly. I have also console logged the data variable 'title' in the mounted lifecycle, and it has data. But the props for the navbar are still empty.

Comment: You are missing an enclosing `export default { }` inside your `<script>` tag. Is it by mistake?

Comment: sorry, this is just an example. i have that in my actual code.

Comment: can you create a sample sandbox?

Comment: Also, do you intend to `post()` or `get()`?

Comment: try to add your `axios` request in `created` method instead of `beforecreate`

Comment: What you have should work. As in, if I create this and instead of the call I resolve a promise with a timeout, it works. Which means the reason is something you're not showing. So, could you create a [mcve] **reproducing** the issue (therefore containing the real cause)!?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-pond-t4o2d?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: First of all, change `:title="this.title"` to `:title="title"`. But it's working: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-albattani-5liwo?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: @JoshWinters The demo you posted doesn't contain axios. Since the rest is very straightforward and should work, the problem is in the request you're making. Did you try to debug it?

Comment: @tao None of the answers are correct. Axios uses promises and retrieves the response asynchronously, regardless of cache. `this.title = response.title` is guaranteed to be evaluated after the component is mounted. It's misleading to use beforeCreated for this but it's certainly not an issue here.

Comment: @Josh, most likely, the problem lies with how you retrieve `title` from the axios call response. Probably replacing `response.title` with `response.data.title` will do the trick. However, a `console.log(response)` should elucidate the matter.

Answer (score 0):

**beforeCreate** is called before data observation. Try again using **beforeMount**

Answer (score 0):

Simply in the `beforeCreate` life cycle method your `data` object not loaded yet so you can't call it at this time so the best practice for this to use `created` method

### beforeCreate()

This is the very first lifecycle hook that gets called in Vue JS, it gets called immediately after the Vue instance has been initialized.

### created()

the second lifecycle hook that is called right after the `beforeCreated` hook. At this stage, the Vue instance has been initialized and has activated the start of things like computed properties, watchers, events, data properties and manipulations that come with it.

[image]

```
created: function(){
    axios.post('')
    .then(response => {
        this.title = response.title
   })
}
```

Comment: You don't follow your own explanation of Vue lifecycle. Data is never accessed when beforeCreated takes place. `this.title = response.title` happens after the component is mounted and thus after created.

Comment: you are right that he can add the request in mounted method but in the most cases it would be better in created method, but that what i explain i didn't talk about mounted method in my explain